# android - Selected photo from gallery rotates in landscape in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using the phonegap file upload to upload files to a server. When i select a portrait photo from the gallery it rotates to landscape

```
 function selectPicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                img.src = uri;
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
            },
            { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,correctOrientation : true, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a "correctOrientation" parameter for getPicture (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) try setting it to false (or true :D)

Hope this helps